# Eclipse randomly exits after installation of Blackberry plugin/SDK

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java-me, windows-xp, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Since adding the Blackberry Java classes from their website into eclipse, I've had it where eclipse will randomly close, with no discernible pattern, rhyme, error or reason. Here is the environment/software packages that I am using:

Windows XP SP2
Eclipse v3.5.1
Blackberry Java Plugin v1.1.1.200911111641-15
Blackberry Java SDK 4.5.0.21

I've tried the usual steps of complete uninstall and reinstallation of Eclipse and the accompanying plugins on multiple systems with the same configuration, including one that had a fresh install of Windows XP SP2. Upgrading to Eclipse 3.6 didn't work (the plugin wont' install as it's the wrong version), nor the downgrade to 3.4 for the same reason. I also increased the heap size to 512 (system has two gigs of memory) as some research into Eclipse doing this type of thing with Groovy was resolved that way, but again, no dice. Eclipse works great when the blackberry plugins are not installed, and no entries of errors or issues in the event log are helping to show what the issue with these plug-ins might be.

So if anyone has ran into this issue, and even better, has a solution, I'd love to hear about it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: An additional to my issue, autoComplete with the Blackberry SDK seems to make this extremely unstable, like almost a guaranteed crash. Is this fixable at all?

---

For anyone that loads this question up trying to find a solution, I've never found a fix. It seems to be a bug with this version of the IDE. If there is a fix, please post.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to downgrade Eclipse to 3.4 (Ganymede)? I experienced similar issues when I tried upgrading Eclipse to something greater than 3.4.2.

Comment: Gave that a shot this morning and no dice. The required plugin for the project needs Eclipse Ganydeme(3.5)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the plugin, not the IDE. Eclipse has always been stable for me until I installed the BB plugin. Since then it crashes all the time. Since I've installed the release (non-beta) version of the plugin that was recently released I can't even get my project to build.

Comment: Well that answers if the release will improve things. Thanks for the update.

Comment: I have managed to get it to work now. I uninstalled the plugin and reinstalled through the Eclipse update site (instead of the standalone installer). Things seem much smoother now.

Instructions: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12794/BlackBerry_Java_Plug-in-Installation_and_Configuration_Guide--933891-1125035846-001-1.1-US.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This could be a manifestation of [this bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283503). Check your `C:\eclipse` directory for files like `hs_err_pidxxxx.log`. The file goes on to explain this error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x753ba053, pid=3144, tid=5820
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.3-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [USP10.dll+0x1a053]
```

I've been experiencing this as well. It's completely debilitating. It causes Eclipse to just up and *crash* out of nowhere (and programming in a language as verbose as Java without Content-Assist is insane).

The bug has been fixed in Eclipse 3.6M7, but unfortunately I can't get the JDE Plug-in to install in the latest release candidate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Eclipse 3.5.X and has been fixed for 3.6.0

Bug Ticket link on Eclipse Bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283503

Looks like we are stuck with this until the next update to the BB Eclipse plugin.